# Current statistics about lethality of appendicitis

Tags: statistics, appendix, appendicitis, appendectomy

I am currently trying to find recent statistics about the lethality rates of appendicitis and lethality rates of surgeries connected to appendicitis (normal and burst appendicitis).

Comment: I found answers to both questions immediately with google searches.

Comment: Very helpful comment. Do you fancy sharing your results?

Comment: I don't really have the time to compose a good answer. Just search for phrases like "appendicitis death rate." Even the Wikipedia article on appendicitis provides pretty good info (and more importantly, links to find more).